# blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check... only happens when validation fails

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, validation, cors

I'm kind of new to Laravel, and I'm making a simple API based project, now I have most of my code up and running, but I'm facing an issue with server side validation. every time the server side validation fails, I get the above CORS error as a response. weirdly, if the validation doesn't fail, I don't get the error, and that only happens when I use my Vue.js front-end for the call, when I use thunder client for the API call, everything works as expected...

as far as I understand, validation errors and CORS policy are not related, and I've figured that it's a configuration problem

```
// this is my sign-up function on the front-end (vue.js)
async signup(state, payload){
      state.commit('SET_Loading', 1)

      payload = {
        "name": payload.name,
        "email": payload.email,
        "password": payload.password,
        "password_confirmation": payload.passwordConfirmation,
        "bio": payload.bio,
        "sex": payload.sex,
        "date_of_birth": payload.dateOfBirth,

      }
      if (cookie.get('access_token') == null) {
        try {
          await axios.post('auth/signup/', payload).then(response => {
            cookie.set('access_token', response.data.access_token)
            this.commit('SET_User', response.data);
            router.push('/').then(() => {
            state.commit('SET_Loading', 0)
            router.go()
            })
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error.message);

        }
      }
      state.commit('SET_Loading', 0)

    },
```

```
//
// this is my sign-up function on the back-end (Laravel)
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'sex' => 'required',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required',
            'bio' => '',
        ]);
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $validated['name'],
            'email' => $validated['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($validated['password']),
            'sex' => $validated['sex'],
            'date_of_birth' => $validated['date_of_birth'],
            'type' => 'user',
            'bio' => $validated['bio']
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'bio' => $user->bio,
        ], 200);
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to glue the error messages that I get from the server to it's corresponding input field.

What I have tried so far:

1. in my App\Http\Middleware\Cors.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
```

2. in my config/cors.php

```
return [
    'paths' => ['*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

What am I expecting? I would like my validation to work properly so I can map the response to the input fields.

ALSO: it would be great if you can tell me if my sign-up functions are good enough or should I make some changes :3

Comment: Is this a production issue? If so, did you configure the nginx cors settings correctly?

Comment: @Aless55 no, it's still in development.

Comment: What happens if you use the Validation facade instead of validate(), and return a JSON response with status 400 for example? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: @Aless55 that did it, thank you... I wonder why though!!

Comment: I wonder also, maybe instead of try catch you could simply use the axios.then(...).catch(...) method and it would work with the first approach

Comment: I don't think that "allow all" CORS middleware is a good idea Laravel already includes a CORS middleware (which is what config/cors.php controls) and that is in the global middleware stack [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#cors)